# Sort Primefaces DataTable column with two Columns names in sortBy attribute

Tags: sorting, primefaces-datatable

I would like to sort a dataTable which has column named "CustomerName" which needs to be sorted based on Customer's FirstName & LastName.
So i'd like to pass value to sortBy attribute as shown below
sortBy="CustomerTable.FirstName,CustomerTable.LastName"

When i try this i get a parser error stating that String

I am able to sort a column with one table name & column name as input like shown below
sortBy="CustomerTable.CustomerNumber"

Comment: What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: primefaces 3.5 @JasperdeVries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sortBy="CONCAT(CustomerTable.FirstName,' ',CustomerTable.LastName)"
This will sort the column in alphabetical order after concatenating the FirstName and LastName columns of CustomerTable